# Drag wide UIImageView?

Tags: ios, scroll, uigesturerecognizer, drag

I want to make a ruler-like application, where I can drag some wide image thats width is about 3-5 time wider then the screen in one dimension (left-right). I suppose there are two ways to do this:

1. Use uigesturerecognizer to touchmove the imageview
2. Use collectionview where the image will be devided to N pieces where N is number of  cells of collection view.

Comment: Why not just have 1 image in a scroll view? It should't be beyond the memory limitations of any of the devices that would run iOS 7 most likely.

Comment: also i need to put little subviews with network-based content to this draggable image. How can I save their positions it case of image in scrollview?

Comment: I don't fully understand you, the subviews would never change their X or Y position once you have placed them. The scroll view scrolls an outer view. once you have placed them they will remain.

Comment: I mean I have to "populate" the draggable ImageView with Views (i.e. users avatars) from DB. Each user has to have his own position.

Comment: Well, each user will have to have their own position whatever method you choose. I'm a bit confused, is this part of the original question or an issue that only arises only using a UIImageView?

Comment: @GaryRiches, yes, this arises using UIImageView. Anyway, thank you for the replies